# Slow load of Magento site

Tags: magento, vps

My Magento site is slow. The domain waiting time is more than 22 seconds.

The site is 33kb and I have a well configured VPS hosting.

How can I speed up my load time?

[image: Image From GTmetrix]

Comment: Please provide us some background information. If you do one millions loop and echo a few string , it could be long. Which cache system is activated ? etc...

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your site page speed through below link:
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/
https://tools.pingdom.com/

And mainly you need to change settings by combining javscript and css for good performance of your website.

Follow steps:

**STEP 1:** NAVIGATE TO THE DEVELOPER MENU
Log into your Magento Admin Panel and navigate to System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer.
[image]
**STEP 2:** CHECK CURRENT CSS AND JS SETTINGS
Under Javascript Settings and CSS Settings, Magento will tell you if it is currently combining these files.
[image]
**STEP 3:** ENABLE CSS AND JS COMBINING
Under Javascript Settings and CSS Settings, set Merge JavaScript Files and Merge CSS Files to Yes.
[image]

Now let's save the changes.
[image]

And check from above tools links and if any help need, please reply.

Also you can use below Full page cache extension:
https://github.com/GordonLesti/Lesti_Fpc
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/30252/
http://www.extendware.com/magento-full-page-cache.html
https://amasty.com/magento-full-page-cache.html
https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/extensions/full-page-cache/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to you use a fpc extension (Full pace caching) or ProxyCaching (example Varnish)

I am using a this fpc extension(https://magegiant.com/magento-full-page-cache-extension) on my magento site. My site speed is increased by 130%

Or you can choose a another fpc on "magento connect" for using. https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/